# Angular two way binding not working inside directive template

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive template as follows.

```
(function () {
   'use strict';

   angular
      .module('testApp', [])
      .directive('leftNav', leftNav);

   /* @ngInject */
   function leftNav() {
      return {
         replace    : true,
         restrict: 'E',
         template:   '<div class="left-nav">' +
         '<left-header title="{{LeftNavCtrl.titleName}}">' +

         '</left-header>' +
         '</div>',
         controller: LeftNavController,
         controllerAs: 'LeftNavCtrl',
         bindToController: true
      }
   }

   function LeftNavController($modal, $scope) {

      var vm = this;


      vm.titleName = "first";

      $scope.$on('changeTitle', function(event, args) {
         vm.titleName = "second";
      });

   }
})();
```

Here, when the page gets rendered very first time, the title will be "first".
And on clicking some button on some other directive, will emit the event and the $scope.on gets called, but the new value is not rendered.

Thanks

Comment: why you are using $scope.titleName  for the first one and then vm.titleName in the watch?

Comment: With `controllerAs` shouldn't you use `this` in the controller body ?

Comment: Updated with the actual code. Still not working.

Comment: Create a [mcve] demo in plunker. We don't know where in the scope tree the emitter is

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me.
I use this in the controller as it is the recommended syntax with controller as.

I also affect it to a local variable in order to be able to reach it in the `$on` function.

In your original snippet you are also not displaying anything, the interpolation of `titleName` is at the level of the title attribute of the `left-header` tag.

```js
angular
      .module('testApp', [])
      .directive('leftNav', leftNav)
      .directive('button', ['$rootScope', button]);

   /* @ngInject */
   function leftNav() {
      return {
         replace    : true,
         restrict: 'E',
         template:   '<div class="left-nav">' +
         '<left-header title="{{LeftNavCtrl.titleName}}">{{LeftNavCtrl.titleName}}' +
         '</left-header>' +
         '</div>',
         controller: LeftNavController,
         controllerAs: 'LeftNavCtrl'
      }
   }

   function button($rootScope) {
      return {
         replace    : true,
         restrict: 'E',
         template:   '<div class="left-nav" ng-click="changeTitle()">Broadcast' +
         '</div>',
         link: function($scope){
           $scope.changeTitle = function(){
             $rootScope.$broadcast('changeTitle');
           }
         }
      }
   }

   function LeftNavController($scope) {
      var ctrl = this;
      ctrl.titleName = "first";

      $scope.$on('changeTitle', function(event, args) {
         ctrl.titleName = "second";
      });

   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp">
  <left-nav>
  </left-nav>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,  The emit event is happening from some other directive and it doesnt work in this case.

Comment: if the directive is a sibling or a parent, $emit will not work.
I recommend the injection of `$rootScope` and the usage of `$rootScope.$broadcast('changeTitle')` in that case.

Comment: $emit is working, but changing the value inside $on not getting reflected.

Comment: It was working in the previous snippet, I changed it to make it from another directive. don't miss the `ctrl.titleName = "second";` as you cannot use `this` in the `$on` function

Comment: Try to run my snippet and click the 'Broadcast' text, you will see the title changing. Then check my controller code carefully.